# webpack 4 images in node_modules : module not found

Tags: webpack-4, webpack-file-loader

### The problem

Im using webpack 4 to compile scss to css and MiniCssExtractPlugin to save the css into a different file. The problem is, that i dont manage to load images and fonts, that are included via url() inside of the scss files. It also makes no difference between running development or production.
Scss is compiled perfectly and without any problems. Also the scss-loader has no problems loading .scss-files from node_modules.
Why does this error occur and how can i fix it?

### error-message when running npm

```
ERROR in ./ui/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./ui/index.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff' in '/home/asdff45/Schreibtisch/Programme/GO/src/factorio-server-manager/manager/ui'
 @ ./ui/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./ui/index.scss) 7:336881-336921

ERROR in ./ui/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./ui/index.scss)
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../webfonts/fa-solid-900.woff2' in '/home/asdff45/Schreibtisch/Programme/GO/src/factorio-server-manager/manager/ui'
 @ ./ui/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./ui/index.scss) 7:336799-336840
```

And multiple more, but all have the same error, just the filename changes.

### webpack-Config

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        // js: './ui/index.js',
        sass: './ui/index.scss'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app')
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ui/js/')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: loader_path => {
                                if(!/node_modules/.test(loader_path)) {
                                    return "app/images/[name].[ext]?[hash]";
                                }

                                return (
                                    "app/images/vendor/" +
                                    loader_path.replace(/\\/g, "/")
                                        .replace(/((.*(node_modules))|images|image|img|assets)\//g, '') +
                                    '?[hash]'
                                );
                            },
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /(\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|otf)$|font.*\.svg$)/,
                loaders: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            name: loader_path => {
                                if (!/node_modules/.test(loader_path)) {
                                    return 'app/fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]';
                                }

                                return (
                                    'app/fonts/vendor/' +
                                    loader_path
                                        .replace(/\\/g, '/')
                                        .replace(/((.*(node_modules))|fonts|font|assets)\//g, '') +
                                    '?[hash]'
                                );
                            },
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "bundle.css"
        })
    ]
}
```

[Project Repo/Branch](https://github.com/knoxfighter/factorio-server-manager/tree/Feature/update-everything-webpack-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader) to your build, like this:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        "css-loader",
        "resolve-url-loader",
        "sass-loader?sourceMap"
    ]
}
```

`resolve-url-loader` is resolving paths to assets based on the original file that is importing the asset.

I tried it locally and the build is now passing :) Cheers!