# Webpack compile showing error for bootstrap 3 sass

Tags: webpack, sass

i am using webpack and Sass for my project.While running webpack i am getting following error

> ERROR in ./src/scss/main.scss
>       Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'

i am using `"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7"` version
here is my webpack.congig.js file

```
module.exports = (env = {}) => {
    return {
        entry: ['./src/js/tdr.js','./src/scss/main.scss'],
        output: {
            filename: 'dist/js/bundle.js',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: 'file-loader',
                            options: {
                                name: '[name].css',
                                outputPath: 'dist/css/'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'extract-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'postcss-loader'
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: where is your babel loader ?

Comment: i have added...still same issue

Comment: please share it over github. I ca dig into it

Comment: Just answered a similar question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52010057/webpack-4-images-in-node-modules-module-not-found/52047694#52047694. You need a `resolve-url-loader` to allow your dependencies to resolve their relative path imports.